# Altium Designer: panelization with test tracks

Tags: altium, panelize

I have a board which I want to place in a panel. I can do it with Place -> Embedded Board Array/Panelize. Easy!

After that I was intended to place additional wiring and connectors **on the panel** (outside the multiplied boards). This wiring tracks should brake when the boards goes off the panel.

This is what I have in 3D view for now:

[image]

As you can see - the tracks should go outside the board edge. The narrower tracks on the bottom are what I tried to draw on the panel But I had to aim blindly! Look what I have in 2D:

[image]

As you can see - no tracks at all! It looks like the boards on the panel is not a board anymore - it is a kind of uneditable object.

In the Altium's documentation:

> but it is not advisable to place any other objects that would
>   represent the actual physical design

Taken from this page: [Embedded Board Array](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-EmbeddedBoardArray((Embedded+Board+Array))_AD)

So it looks like I'm trying to use the tool in the way it is not intended to be used at all.

It's time for **QUESTIONS**:

1. Am I able to see tracks in 2D view of the panel?
2. Is there any tools in Altium to do this out-of-the-board wiring in a way to reduce human error probability (whis is high if I'd place tracks in PCB without a schematic representations and without DRC control)?
3. What will happen with the tracks after the FR4 bridge under them would break? Probably I should place V-grove on the opposite side of the panel, should I?

Comment: Use a Gerber viewer on the final Gerber output.

Comment: @brian, how can this help?

Comment: A Gerber viewer will show whether the tracks are on the information you're going to make the boards from.

Comment: I agree with @Brian.  Also consider putting wide traces, or smt pads on your PCB, so your aim on the panel won't need to be super precise.  Disclaimer: I have not tried this...  Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: ...also, as far as I know, there's no way to put an object on the native pcb, and have it be 'snap-able'-to on the embedded board array panel.  I've often wanted this for placing dimensions.

Comment: Alternatively, use a bed of nails like everybody else. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/145468/icsp-or-pre-programmed-microcontroller/145485#145485

Comment: V-grooves go on both sides so I think your traces will be severed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany just talted to manufacturer: you're right, V-groove goes on both sides.

Comment: From the comments above I see that this is a bad idea. However nobody really tries to do so. Right?

Comment: Aussie bloke Dave Jones has a video in which he talks aboot it. Worth watching. They may have changed the way the panel behaves though- I don't usually fiddle with the generated panel, only add tooling holes and such like.