# Battery connectors: how are they called?

Tags: connector, surface-mount

How is this 3 pad connector called? I'm trying to build something similar into a product but can't seem to find anything similar.

[image: mobile phone battery]

Comment: Is that the end of an insertable battery module? If so those contacts are generally custom designed as part of the module itself. It will generally not be possible to find that as an off the shelf part. (Note that the mating spring contact battery connector may be an available part but may also be a custom part designed into the housing to which the shown module is inserted).

Comment: Yes they're the battery contacts. I found some female modular contacts that look just about the same but they're ridiculously expensive at some $3 each.

Comment: Just make a small PCB and specify hard gold plating for the contacts in that area.

Comment: Was trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can build them using spring-loaded contacts such as [pogo pins.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_pin) This is what many universal mobile phone chargers use (they allow you to slide the pins around so they mate up, e.g. [see here).](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/146175/40673)

Comment: I saw a lot of spring-loaded pins and other things but they are expensive, it only makes sense using those for a larger device. I'm trying to build a very small and very affordable device, it would make no sense paying $.80/pc (times 5 contacts) when the entire device including mcu, power, radio costs $12.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you are making a product that needs a battery but you are not prepared to tool up a custom design then I would strongly suggest that you look at the possibility to source an existing 3rd party battery and concentrate on the other aspects of your product. Adapt your product around that battery selected.

Make sure to select something that was or is widely used in the market place. For example you would do well to select a battery style from something like a Panasonic point and shoot camera that has several alternate sources for its batteries and sold world wide as opposed to some special battery pack made for a portable baby monitor.

Comment: Not trying to make a battery but a device of a comparable size and shape that plugs into a custom socket and need to add a connector similar to that one.

Comment: Then best I can recommend is to destructively analyze a few modules that have contacts like that to see how they are custom designed and fitted to the module. Then adapt those concepts to your design. It sounds like you are already prepared for a custom tooling of your device so just adapt it as necessary. One system I've seen used on devices with low insert/remove cycle count is to embed a narrow circuit board, that has gold plated pads, into the end of the module case behind windows where the external spring loaded contacts can poke in.

Comment: "destructively analyze" - reminds me of the "I suggest a radical dislocation" comment from voyager